# How to install Xamarin SDK (on Ubuntu) without Visual Studio

Tags: .net, xamarin

I want to create a build machine for my Xamarin.Forms project. Is there a way to install Xamarin SDK without need to install VS?

So far I've managed to:

- create VPS with Ubuntu & docker,
- install dotnet 5,
- install java 16.

Following options are acceptable:

- install Xamarin SDK directly, so that I can run `dotnet/msbuild MySolution.sln` and get Xamarin.Forms projects built,
- get docker image based on windows-nano so that solution can be built in container (though I want image size to be as small as possible, due to storage size limitations - I want to fit all needed SDKs in less than 9 Gb).

Comment: For `Xamarin.Android` Microsoft has Linux/macOS build from source instructions : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/README.md#building-from-source For `Xamarin.iOS` you will need macOS.