# Xamarin Android SDK is not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, jetbrains-ide

I am under Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to do C# development (Web, Mobile and Unity) for this I installed the software RIDER from JetBrains but there is an error when creating a Xamarin Forms project which is the following ""**Xamarin Android SDK is not found**"".
Can you help me to solve this problem please?
[image]

I would like you to propose a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674961/how-to-install-xamarin-sdk-on-ubuntu-without-visual-studio